# Can you make coffee by boiling it?

Tags: coffee, tea

Google results have confused me so much. I [learned](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PSf5RCbTtyY) to make a [Nescafe Classic](https://www.amazon.in/Nescafe-Classic-Coffee-Stabilio-200g/dp/B01MY2Y30O/ref=mp_s_a_1_5?keywords=nescafe%20classic&qid=1569406933&s=pantry&sprefix=Nescafe%20classic&sr=8-5) coffee a year ago.

All I would do is: Add some coffee and sugar in a mug/cup, add a few drops of water or milk and start shaking it with spoon. A few minutes later it changes it's color and becomes a paste. It releases the flavors. Now you can add hot water or milk according to your taste. Most YouTube videos also show similar results and believe in this *theory*. That's it.

Now Google results like [this](https://www.quora.com/Do-you-boil-coffee-or-do-you-pour-boiling-water-on-the-coffee?ch=10&share=a68c2f07&srid=noiR) really confuse sometimes. Kindly don't write your answer based on just this link. If you search "should you boil coffee" you'll see tons of articles or answers that nowhere tells a method like shaking and making a paste before adding the milk or water to get the flavor. They will support your Google search and say like:

1. Boil water and then add coffee in it
2. Add coffee in water and boil it
3. Heat water and add coffee in it

And so on.

Why is it like this? If flavor can be accieved by the method I described above, why people use *boil* mothod?

Comment: Most hits you'll see on making coffee are likely to be about ground coffee rather than nescafe. If you're going to use instant coffee, just pour hot water on it, add milk to taste, and you're done.

Comment: Hi! Can you edit your question to include the information that you're using *instant* coffee? It is generating some confusion in the answer section.

Comment: Edited the details

Comment: 2nd link is broken. First link appears to be a 5 minute video on how to make instant coffee. I didn't watch it.

Comment: Link you provided refers to brewing coffe. Making instant coffe is not brewing. It's just rehydrating dried coffe that was already brew.

Comment: Brew = Bring flavours to coffee?

Comment: You're putting far to much effort into instant coffee. Just mix coffee, water and sugar (if desired). add milk/creamer (if desired). Done. Attempting to 'brew' instant coffee serves no purpose.

Comment: @brhans most people and videos I have seen making this Nescafe Classic coffee, they first blend it till it changes color, then add other stuff. Why would they do it if it serves no purpose

Comment: Ok - I've just watched the video you linked to - and that has to be the strangest method of making instant coffee I've ever seen ... I'f you're going to spend that much time & ritual on a single cup of coffee then it would be better spent doing a pour-over using 'real' ground coffee. Nescafe is not at all uncommon in both the country I'm originally from and the country where I currently live and I've never seen or heard of the method shown in that video. I guess if you're aiming towards something resembling a cappuccino then this gets you somewhere close ...

Comment: Whoever shot that video either doesn't know the meaning of the word "instant" or thinks Nescafe is hot chocolate, with all the whisking business.  I could make *and drink* a cup of instant coffee in the time they spend fiddling about

Comment: @vikas "brew" doesn't mean "bring out flavors", it means "make liquid coffee from coffee beans". Using the been "brew" in combination with instant coffee is very confusing, many people would argue that this verb does not apply at all when using instant coffee.

Comment: The thing about Nescafe is that no matter how much faff you put into the preparation, it's **still** going to taste more like gravy browning once you've finished ;) Of all the instant coffees I've ever tasted, it really is the least like coffee.

Comment: Just a quick note - OP was talking to me about this on chat... and.. Its Dalgona coffee, or a very similar preparation.

Answer (score 2):

Coffee hates boiling water - or more specifically, water boiling at 100°C - it scalds it & kills the taste.
but read on...

There are basically two kinds of instant coffee, spray dried & freeze dried.
Both start by making up 'real' coffee.

Spray drying is achieved by then super-heating the mixture & spraying it out into an evaporator. The powder falls to the bottom where it is collected [Whether they leave it as powder or clump it is either a design choice or a method limitation, I've never found out which].

Freeze drying is achieved by reducing the atmospheric pressure then spraying in a similar way. This means they can work at much lower temperatures, as water boils at a lower temperature the lower the pressure.

The second method is more expensive than the first. It preserves the flavours a lot better, so tends to be reserved for blends & beans that were higher quality to start with. Pure arabicas will almost always be freeze dried.

So, your Nescafe is made by the first method - spray drying - & therefore has already been ruined/scalded by the process. This is one reason [amongst many] that spray dried coffees taste nothing at all like actual fresh coffee.
Pouring boiling water on this can now have no further effect. "It's already dead, Jim."

Pouring boiling water on freeze dried, however, will spoil it. Freeze dried has so far avoided the scalding.

You can test this by making 3 very simple black coffees.
One teaspoon of freeze dried coffee granules in each cup. To one, add half a cup of cold water, to the second add just half an inch. The third, leave with just granules. Pour absolutely boiling water [the second the kettle clicks off] onto all three to make a full cup. Stir, leave 1 minute & examine all 3. The first will be quite cloudy & mid-dark brown. the second will 'look like coffee'. The third will be almost black & very clear.
Taste them all. They will taste in order from, 'a bit grainy', just right, 'ooh, spoiled'.
You can try this test with spray dried, but the results are not as distinct.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99184/discussion-on-answer-by-tetsujin-can-you-make-coffee-by-boiling-it).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure the answer to your question, but you should look into Turkish style coffee. The style is based on grinding the beans super fine and then boiling it with water. This is a decent primer. https://foolproofliving.com/how-to-make-turkish-coffee/

Specifically pay attention to the foam that forms after boiling. I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Careful: I am pretty sure that the asker is using *instant* coffee, not ground coffee beans.

Comment: Turkish coffee is also somewhat of a special case, as you pull the serving from it three times, before boil, at boil & after boil.